# Parsing a json tree for immediate children in python

Tags: python, json, tree

I have a json tree of the form:

```
{"id":461000008221732864, "reply":0, "children":[{"id":461000467841945602, "reply":1, "children":[{"id":461006562006298624, "reply":1, "children":[{"id":461007094007595008, "reply":1, "children":[{"id":461011959173771264, "reply":1, "children":[{"id":461012787896926209, "reply":1, "children":[{"id":461014469586329600, "reply":1, "children":[{"id":461014847279210496, "reply":1, "children":[]}]}]}]}]}]},{"id":461000724520787969, "reply":1, "children":[]}]}]}
```

I have to keep a count of reply = 0 or reply = 1 for every node amongst its immediate children. i.e For every node I have to check its immediate children for reply =0/1. I have written a code for finding the number of nodes in a tree. But not able to figure out where should I keep a count for immediate children to check for reply flag. Please help me.

```
import json

# method to recursively browse the elements
def get_children(node):
    stack = [node]
    while stack:
        node = stack.pop()
        stack.extend(node['children'][::-1])
        yield node

# open the file and parse its JSON contents
f = open('filename.json','r')
rep_dic = {}
size_dic = {}
for line in f:
    d = json.loads(line)
    child_dic = {}
    rep = 0
    for child in get_children(d):
        if child not in child_dic:
            child_dic[child["id"]] = 1
            if child["reply"] == 1:
                rep += 1
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "keep a count for immediate children"? What is the expected output, and what are you getting instead?

Comment: So this `JSON` structure, once parsed, is a Python dictionary, with repeated nesting.  A `child` is a list, for which `d1[i].keys()` is `['reply', 'children', 'id']`.  So at each level there's a `reply` and another `child` level.  All `reply==1` except the top most.  At most levels the list has len 1.